# Magento2: How to setup PWA Studio on website?

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio

Why we should use PWA Studio?

How to setup PWA Studio on Magento community addition?

Please help in this

Comment: follow https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/ this it will help you

Comment: Is it support with Magento 2.0? @AsadKhan

Comment: Yes but for the Magento version 2.3 and above.

Comment: No its only for 2.3 and above versions. The concept of PWA in M2 was included in M 2.3 or above versions

Comment: Ok, Thanks @AsadKhan

Comment: Ok, Thanks @FaisalSheikh

Comment: @MasudShaikh Pleasure!